# Plot edges of a tree in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graphics, plot

What is an effective way to plot a list of coordinates in the form [(x1,y1),(x2,y2)], where each pair of coordinates is connected by a line (as shown below). I'd like to avoid use of non-core packages (core being pandas, matplotlib, numpy, ...)

Example:

```
c = [[(0, 4), (1, 3)],
     [(0, 4), (1, 5)],
     [(1, 3), (2, 2)],
     [(1, 3), (2, 4)],
     [(1, 5), (2, 4)],
     [(1, 5), (2, 6)],
     [(2, 2), (3, 1)],
     [(2, 2), (3, 3)],
     [(2, 4), (3, 3)],
     [(2, 4), (3, 5)],
     [(2, 6), (3, 5)],
     [(2, 6), (3, 7)]]
```

to be plotted as (with labels):

[image]

Comment: You said: "where each pair of coordinates is connected by a line". What is the rule of connecting coordinates? For example, you did not connect `(0, 4)` and `(2, 4)`.

Comment: I think this might be helpful `https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot`

Comment: @dopstar: good question. There is no pair `[(0,4),(2,4)]`, so we do not connect it with a line :) However, there is a pair `[(0, 4), (1, 3)]`, so we do connect it (as shown). Should be fairly straight forward, but let me know if further clarity is needed.

Comment: @Nader. Thanks for a reference. I clarified above: trying to use only core packages (matplotlib, pandas, etc.).

Comment: I believe you're looking for something like this: http://matplotlib.org/users/path_tutorial.html

Comment: @EmilyHill Ok I get you. By the way your data is wrong `(1, 5)` does not connect to `(2, 4)` in the data but it is in the plot.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. fixed it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of the 'effective way' I'm not sure. What follows is the working way which I think can be tuned/tweaked to be 'more effective'?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

c = [[(0, 4), (1, 3)],
     [(0, 4), (1, 5)],
     [(1, 3), (2, 2)],
     [(1, 3), (2, 4)],
     [(1, 5), (2, 4)],  # I changed this to match your plot
     [(1, 5), (2, 6)],
     [(2, 2), (3, 1)],
     [(2, 2), (3, 3)],
     [(2, 4), (3, 3)],
     [(2, 4), (3, 5)],
     [(2, 6), (3, 5)],
     [(2, 6), (3, 7)]]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

annotated = set()
for l in c:
    d = [[p[0] for p in l], [p[1] for p in l]]
    ax.plot(d[0], d[1], 'k-*')
    for p in l:
        annotated.add(p)

for p in annotated:
    ax.annotate(str(p), xy=p)

plt.xlim([0, 3.5])
plt.ylim([0, 8])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Nicely engineered! Thanks!